# Função Group By SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sou iniciante em `SQL Server`, gostaria de uma ajuda para entender a função `Group By` de forma simples. Tanto seu conceito quanto a forma de utilizar... para quem puder me ajudar agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem algumas funções como COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM e AVG, nas quais elas agrupam algum resultados, vamos supor que você faça:

```
select COUNT(nome) from pessoa
```

Isso ira agrupar todos os nomes em um resultado, gerando então a conta os nomes, vamos supor que temos 4 nomes o resultado do sum seria 4.

Mas vamos supor que você queria conta os nomes iguais, então você faria

```
select COUNT(nome) from pessoa group by nome
```

Assim ele vai agrupar todos os nomes iguais e mostrar a quantidade, então vamos supor que destes 4 existam 2 nomes iguais joão e os outros dois diferentes, então o resultado seria 2 por causa dos dois joão e depois teríamos mais dois resultados 1 e 1 referentes aos nomes diferentes que sobraram.

**Veja alguns exemplos**

[Exemplo 1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby)
[Exemplo 2](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby_orderby)
[Exemplo 3](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby1)

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: ótimo exemplo, ficou bem mais fácil entender como utilizar a função... agradeço a ajuda!